# Eclipse Android SDK unresolved R variable + unknown required load command 0x80000022

Tags: java, android

Android SDK and ECLIPSE on MAC
My "Hello World" project won't run, compiler errors.
Getting unresolved R variable and unknown required load command 0x80000022
Followed some of the posted fixes, still no go?

Comment: try to update your eclipse

Comment: Your Mac OS version? Java version?

Comment: Unfortunately Android Eclipse SDK does not works on Mac OS X 10.5.8. If that is the case, upgrading to Mac OS X 10.6.8, your issue will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks @Gokul, I downloaded latest package same result, looks like my OS needs upgrade from 10.5.8

Comment: Fixed by using brand new Macbook runs 100%, bit drastic